# Cant find VBA equivalent to this c# code

Tags: c#, vba

Here is the c# code:

```
 if (emailBody.Contains("<CENTER>"))
           {
               emailBody = emailBody.Remove(0, emailBody.IndexOf("<CENTER>"));

               if (emailBody.Contains("</CENTER>"))
               {
                   emailBody = emailBody.Remove(emailBody.IndexOf("</CENTER>") + 10);
               }
           }
```

I have changed it to VBA as below:

```
 If InStr(emailbody, "<CENTER>") > 0 Then
 emailbody = emailbody.Remove(0, **emailbody**.IndexOf("<CENTER>")) ''COMPILE ERROR

    If InStr(emailbody, "</CENTER>") > 0 Then
     emailbody = emailbody.Remove(emailbody.IndexOf("</CENTER>") + 10)

    End If

End If
```

But it wont compile gives error on line stated above :Compile Error, Invalid Qualifier .
 Any suggestions?

Comment: Is emailbody a string?  strings don't have properties or methods in VBA.

Comment: @Rob Yes it is a string. How can i achieve the above ?

Comment: You probably want to use the replace function: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bt3szac5(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: and InStr: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8460tsh1(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: @Rob I want to use remove,because i want to remove all the text from start till <Centre> and all from </Centre> till end, replace would only replace some .

Comment: @confusedMind cant you replace with blank string?

Comment: @AshReva not sure what you mean as i need to remove all text from start till </Centre> , how do it get that text?

Comment: @confusedMind i meant for example like this Dim withoutParts As String = Replace(emailbody , **emailbody**.IndexOf("<CENTER>"), "")

Comment: @AshReva ah , i get it  let me try that..

Comment: I wonder if `Remove` applies to `string`

Comment: @AshReva the replace takes all parameters as string so i dont thin we can put starting index of text.

Comment: @confusedMind that is upto you from where you want to replace. I just gave you idea to replace with blank string

Comment: @AshReva nope cannot figure out if it can be done with Replace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want to get only <center> element from the emailBody.

```
si = InStr(emailBody, "<center>")
ei = InStr(emailBody, "</center>")
emailBody = Mid(emailBody, si, ei - si + 9)
```

The following VBA code is equivalent of C#

```
If InStr(emailBody, "<CENTER>") > 0 Then
    emailBody = Mid(emailBody, InStr(emailBody, "<CENTER>"))
    If InStr(emailBody, "</CENTER>") > 0 Then
        emailBody = Mid(emailBody, 1, InStr(emailBody, "</CENTER>") + 9)
    End If
End If
```

Comment: You have to convert the input string to lower case (use "LCase"); in its current version, it does not work with the OP's input. Also bear in mind that the OP's code does not just retrieve the text between the tags: "emailbody.IndexOf("</CENTER>") + 10" goes one character beyond ">".

Comment: @confusedMind It does not work perfectly. This code does not deliver what your C# version does.

Comment: @varocarbas ... yes, the argument should be uppercase "&lt;CENTER&gt;" in InStr function. si and ei should be checked for greater than zero or not. If si > 0 and ei > 0 then perform Mid() statement will deliver what C# version does.

Comment: Please update your code: write InStr(LCase(emailBody), "<center>"). And emailBody = Mid(emailBody, si, ei - si + 9) should be changed to emailBody = Mid(emailBody, si, ei - si + 10) because this is what the original C# does (up to the last tag + one character... although the OP does not seem to be aware of that). Bear in mind that this is meant to be read by others; if you claim (and the OP confirms it) that certain code delivers a proper conversion C# -> VBA, it should be a proper one. PS: remember that these functions do not support HTML instructions ;)

Comment: @varocarbas  but it does work , even with <centre> and in the html i have <CENTRE>.

Comment: @confusedMind what I proposed was ignoring caps:  InStr(LCase(emailBody), "<center>") means "convert all the content into lower caps and look for center". While performing string comparisons, this (all to lower or all to upper) is the standard proceeding. Actually your original code was faulty because of being able only to account for CENTER, but not for CeNTER, for example. This bit was not in your code, but was undoubtedly an improvements and thus Tun... should have included it (at least, he should have updated his code as suggested to account for the last character as yours).

Answer (score 0):

This should remove the tags:

```
emailbody = Replace( emailbody, "<CENTER>", "" )
emailbody = Replace( emailbody, "</CENTER>", "" )
```